# Coin throw probability on a chessboard square

Tags: statistics, probability, probability-theory

I need some insights on the following problem. You are given a coin whose diameter is equivalent to half the length of a chessboard unit square. If you throw the coin on the board, what is the probability that it lands completely within a single square?

Here is what I need to know,

1. Does it matter here that the chessboard has  64 (8 X 8) squares? Or should I just concentrate on a single square?
2. Is this probability simply the coin's area  (since it is a unit square)?

I am asking because it appears quite easy and odd! Please let me know if I am overthinking.

Thank you.

Here is what I did,

The area of a circle is given by the formula A = πr^2, where r is the radius. Since the coin's diameter is 0.5 units, the radius is half of that, which is 0.5/2 = 0.25 units.

The area of the coin is then A = π(0.25)^2 = 0.1963495.

The area of a single square on the chessboard is simply the side length squared, which is 1 square unit.

To find the probability that the coin lands completely within a single square, I divided the area of the nickel by the area of a square:

P = A of coin / A of square = 0.1963495 / 1

Calculating this probability:

P ≈ 0.1963

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Welcome to SO! As written, this question appears to be asking for general probability advice; it may more appropriate for Cross Validated (https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Questions here must be about a specific programming problem (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20only%20accepts%20certain,it%20will%20likely%20be%20closed.). Please adjust your question according to the recommendations at the link or it may be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try thinking of the problem in terms of the center point of the circle, and where this center point is permitted to fall if the coin is to be entirely within a square.  Take an empty box, and a coin with an ink dot on its center point, placed in one of the box's corners.  Then trace along the entire boundary of the box with the coin, the center point of the coin will draw out a rectangle within the box.  If the diameter of the coin is half the square size, then the inner drawn square will have side lengths of 1/2 (relative to the side length of the squares).

So, this inner square has an area of 0.25 (0.5 * 0.5), while the outer square has an area of 1.  The probability of your coin landing perfectly within a square is therefore 0.25.

Diagram for reference:
[image]

Comment: Wonderful insight!

I guess there is no point thinking about the 64 squares on the chessboard!

Comment: You could extend this diagram to 64 squares by visualising it as a tile pattern on each square, however, the ratio of green area to white area will still remain the same, so the same logic extends to the full board.  Allowing for the possibility of the coin falling off the board would be another story.

Comment: @KELVINMWAKAMUIA Could you mark this as correct if it answered your question?  It looks like there are no more answers arriving.